# Split list by sequential entries

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list with some entries being sequential and some not.  I would like to construct a list of lists split by sequential entries.  In this context, sequential means the integer value increases by 1.

Please note that in some cases, there are more than two sequential elements (only up to 3 in this example but in practice could be more).

I thought that some combination of Sow/Reap would work but couldn't figure out how to use those.

```
countByPosition = {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 62, 63, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 64, 65, 191, 192, 193, \
1, 2, 191, 192, 193, 1, 2, 191, 192, 193, 1, 2, 191, 192, 193, 1, 2, \
191, 192, 193, 1, 2, 191, 192, 193, 1, 2, 191, 192, 1, 2, 191, 192, \
1, 2, 191, 192, 1, 2, 191, 192, 1, 2, 191, 192, 1, 2, 191, 192};
```

I have an extremely crude way of generating what I want and am hoping for a more elegant solution.

```
resultList = {};
subList = {countByPosition[[1]]};
lastEntry = countByPosition[[1]];
For[i = 2, i <= Length[countByPosition], i++,
 If[
   countByPosition[[i]] - lastEntry == 1,
   AppendTo[subList, countByPosition[[i]]];
   lastEntry = countByPosition[[i]];
   ,
   AppendTo[resultList, subList];
   subList = {countByPosition[[i]]};
   lastEntry = countByPosition[[i]];
   ];
 ];

resultList
(* {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {62, 63}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {64, 
  65}, {191, 192, 193}, {1, 2}, {191, 192, 193}, {1, 2}, {191, 192, 
  193}, {1, 2}, {191, 192, 193}, {1, 2}, {191, 192, 193}, {1, 
  2}, {191, 192, 193}, {1, 2}, {191, 192}, {1, 2}, {191, 192}, {1, 
  2}, {191, 192}, {1, 2}, {191, 192}, {1, 2}, {191, 192}, {1, 2}} *)
```

All suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

```
Split[countByPosition, #2 == # + 1 &]
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant, as always.